# Cant make jump in gamemaker studio2

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I can't make the jump work in my game made in game maker studio 2
this project uses gravity and the game maker's language.

this is now just random words so stack overflow lets me post this question so Minecraft is a cool game :).

here is the code:

```
/// @description this is the create event
```

// You can write your code in this editor

```
sprite_index=Sprite1;
image_speed = 1;
image_index = 0;
```

step event:

```
    /// @description Insert description here
// You can write your code in this editor

#region //gravedad 
if place_free(x,y+1){

gravity =1;

}else{

gravity=0;

}

if vspeed >=20{vspeed=20}

#endregion

#region //movimiento
if keyboard_check(ord("D")){

direction=0
speed = brr;


}
else{

speed=0;

}

if keyboard_check(ord("A")){

direction=180
speed = brr;


}

if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) && !place_free(x,y+1){

vspeed = -broo;


}
#endregion
```

Comment: Hi Pio, You could rather use the random words to tell more about your problem. For example: What is the expected result and what is the current result? Have you also tried debugging so you can understand what the code tries to do? A lot of problems where you don't know what's going on can be solved by debugging. (placing breakpoints and going through the code step by step).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `!place_free(x,y+1)` is the problem here

```
if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) && !place_free(x,y+1){
    vspeed = -broo;
}
```

Assuming place_free checks if there's no collision, it may either be a case of setting the origin point of the player object to the bottom center, or not having a solid instance or collision mask. (as seen in the [manual](https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Movement_And_Collisions/Collisions/place_free.htm))

I personally prefer using `place_meeting` to check on collisions with a specific object, and ignore the requirements needed for `place_free` to work, maybe that could work better for you.